# $top param not working while using GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl in Sharepoint Online

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In Sharepoint Online I have the following folder structure:

```
-Library "Proceedings".
   -Proceeding 1 (this is a folder)
   -Proceeding 2
   -Proceeding 3
      -Step 1
      -Step 2
      -Step n
   -Proceeding 4
   -Proceeding n
```

I want to retrieve all fields from all files of a certain proceeding so now I am using this call:
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/site/Proceedings/ID of proceeding')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields

I have a problem with this. Some proceedings have more than 5000 files inside so I have a list view threshold error. I've tried using this call instead:

_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/site/Proceedings/ID of proceeding')/Files?$top=15&$skip=0&$expand=ListItemAllFields

But $top is not working. (When the proceeding has less than 5000 files it does work tough)

How can I retrieve all files from a proceeding with more than 5000 files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's list view threshold is a pain to work with. For your requirements you'll need to make multiple calls and use a filter on an indexed column like:

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/site/Proceedings/ID of proceeding')/Files?$filter=Id lt 4999&$top=15&$skip=0&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

After making this call use 'next' endpoint from return result to query again until the 'next' is null.

Comment: But it will allways ruturns files with ID lt 4999. What about if for example I have one file with ID 6520 and another one with ID 21302. I think that maybe i could increment lt filter but how do I know when to stop?

Comment: Read this - After making this call use 'next' endpoint from return result to query again until the 'next' is null.
FYI - the next endpoint will have the next list item id